# What is the meaning of 'under review' after making a minor revision?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review

Last week I received a minor revision decision letter from a journal's editor. I made revisions in accordance with the reviewers' comments and resubmit the manuscript to the ScholarOne system. And now the status still is 'under review'. I wonder whether it means the resubmitted manuscript is now reviewed by external reviewers, or by the editors.

Comment: The revised journal needs to go back to the reviewers.  Some times new reviewers will be sought if currents ones are not available.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus At many journals, "minor revisions" means it will not go back to the reviewers.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your sharing. I'm not sure if the minor revised manuscript is under editor review or referees' review.

Comment: @jakebeal in my area, minor means go back to the reviewers.  Recently one of my articles went to entirely new reviewers after a minor revision and was rejected!

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus Please note that this doesn't contradict my statement at all: I merely noted that the practice varies from journal to journal.